# How to begin repairing this wood corner siding?

Tags: wood, brick, siding

I noticed my house has a hole in this corner siding where wood meets the brick. Any ideas how to repair it (just some basic guidance)?

[image: corner siding]

Answer (score 1):

1. Nail or screw it back together where the two boards meet. Splitless siding nails would be ok, but pre-drill for the ones near the ends of the boards. Trim-head screws are also good. Some are self-drilling, which prevents splits.
2. Nail it to the wall. I can't tell how it was originally fastened, but those same splitless siding nails should do fine, or more trim-head screws.
3. Fill the hole at the bottom to prevent pest intrusion. Spray foam could work but is messy. I'd probably stuff it with steel wool, as I assume it doesn't need additional insulation.

Answer (score 0):

I love spray foam with the help of some silicone. One note, wood shouldn't touch concrete so it won't mold from moisture so perhaps something like a few strips poly sheeting there.

Comment: "spray foam with the help of some silicone". For those of us uneducated in this technique, care to [edit] your answer to expand on that? I seriously have absolutely no idea what that means or why/how you'd add silicone to spray foam.